# How to write R function that prints out residual plot interpretation

Tags: r

Can someone tell me how to write an R function that tests normality and homoscedasticity of the residuals of any given model. Moreover, the function must also print a message that interprets the results from the tests.

I've made the function that prints out the plots but i don't know how to print out its respective interpretation

```
Residuals <- function(model) {
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  plot(model)
  
}
Residuals()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `which` argument for `plot()` to specify which plots you want; whether you use `par(mfrow)` is a personal preference. I'm not sure what you mean by interpretation, but you can add a call of `summary(model)` to print the results. You could also potentially use `report()` to print out a short text summary of your results.

```
data(mtcars)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)

res_func <- function(model) {
  par(mfrow = c(1,2)) # depends if you want them side by side or not
  plot(model, ask = FALSE, which = c(2,3))
  summary(model)
}

res_func(model = mod)

# other option
library(report)

res_func2 <- function(model) {
  par(mfrow = c(1,2)) # depends if you want them side by side or not
  plot(model, ask = FALSE, which = c(2,3))
  report(model)
}

res_func2(model = mod)
```